# Xpath expression matching several attributes for HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, xpath

Assuming I want to find a table with certain width and height attributes 
No problem with

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@width='500']");
```

Would it be possible to add height='500' somehow to this Xpath expression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with logical "and" operator:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@width='500' and @height='500']");
```